# Tcpclient multiple clients connect to server

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

A client need to build several tcp connections to server simultaneously.
My Server's code is below.

```
while (_running)
{
    if (!_listener.Pending())
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        continue;
    }

    TcpClient client = _listener.AcceptTcpClient();
}
```

And my client's code is below.

```
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    TcpClient tcp = new TcpClient();
    tcp.Connect(_server);
}
```

The first connection is success. But the second connection is failed due to server's no response(Actually server are listening tcp connection).
However, if I add `Thread.Sleep(1500)` after each of tcp.Connect(), all connections are success. But this situation is only true if there are one client and one server. If there are many clients then how can I ensure each connection that can be accepted by server? Also why I add Thread.Sleep can make such connections succeed?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same task. I looked for canonical implementation of this task for .Net with no luck.
The approach I use now is descibed below.

**Main idea**

We need listener to receive connection, give the connection to the handler, and as soon as possible start listen for a new connection.

**Implementation**

```
AutoResetEvent _stopEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
object _lock = new object();

public void StartListening()
{
    _listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(ConnectionHandler, null);
    _stopEvent.WaitOne();//this part is different in my original code, I don't wait here
}

public void StopListening()
{
    lock(_lock)
    {
        listener.Stop();
        listener = null;                
    }

    _stopEvent.Set();//this part is different in my original code
}

void ConnectionHandler(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    lock(_lock)
    {
        if(_listener == null)
            return;

        var tcpClient = _listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(asyncResult);
        var task = new MyCustomTask(tcpClient);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(task.Execute);

        _listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(ConnectionHandler,null);             
    }
}
```

I am still not very confident in calling _listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient in ConnectionHandler, but I haven't found alternative way.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are still no satisfied answers and I finally use different approach to handle my case. I found out that using class `Socket` is faster and more stable than using `TcpListener` and `TcpClient`. I tried different approach to use `TcpListener` and `TcpClient`. Firstly, I used `TcpListener.AcceptTcpClient` to listen client with and without `TcpListener.Pending` but there is still possibly ignoring some client connection. Sencondly, I used asynchronous method, `TcpListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient` and `TcpListener.EndAcceptTcpClient` but still no succeeded, still ignoring some client connection. Finally using `Socket.Accept` instead of `TcpListener.AcceptTcpClient`, the former one has nearly no delay and really fast to response to client.

Comment: The delay in accepting clients was due to the wasteful sleep in your code, not to any shortcoming in the API.